# ¿Como concatenar un valor con el ORDER BY? - Nodejs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Cual seria la manera correcta de concatenar el valor que tengo en la constante data en mi query MySQL? De la manera que estoy haciendo no funciona.

```
const data = req.body;

req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM ordenar_usuario ORDER BY ', data, (err, usuarios) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        res.render('ordenar', {
            data: usuarios
        });
    });
```

Comment: `req.body` siempre es un objeto. Imprímelo en la consola para ver qué llaves tiene. ¿Qué conector estás usando? posiblemente tengas que añadir un placeholder a la query con el nombre del campo con que quieres ordenar, dado que se llame igual en la tabla y en el body

Comment: Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con Nodejs. Estoy usando express-myconnection.

Comment: Cuando imprimo en el console me sale un [object object]

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(req.body))` o bien `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(req.body)))`

Answer (score 0):

Te construí un ejemplo que espero te sea de utilidad, donde solo concatene el valor de una variable que llamé `id` para pasarselo a la consulta

La consulta la meto entre comillas `""` y al final dicha variable solo la concateno así: `+id`

**EJEMPLO**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    'server': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'secret',
    'port': '3307',
    'database': 'data'
})

connection.connect()

app.get('/all', function(req, res){
    let id = 1
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = "+id, function(errors, results, fields){
        console.log(results)
    })
})

app.listen('8000', () => {
    console.log("running")
})
```

Al final por consola me arroja lo siguiente

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    nameUser: 'gatito',
    passwordUser: 'password',
    statusUser: 1,
    created_at: 2018-10-10T14:40:14.000Z } ]
```

Comment: En mi navegador aparece esto: "SELECT * FROM ordenar_usuario ORDER BY [object Object]"}

Comment: En la consola me muestra eso: Server on port 3000
{}
GET /ordenar?ordem=nome 200 65.814 ms - 307
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: tienes algo así en tu código? `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");`

Comment: No, no tengo nada parecido en ninguna parte.

Comment: se me hace extraño, requiero hacer otro ejemplo y checar ese error

Comment: Yo puedo buscar un usuario por su id o por su nombre, pero cuando se trata de usar el ORDER BY (quiero ordenar los usuarios por edad o nombre) no consigo hacer la consulta.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo no se responde correctamente tu pregunta, pero con la función fetch utilizo algo similar y usando la misma lógica, serviría así: `'SELECT * FROM ordenar_usuario ORDER BY ' + data + ''`

Suerte

Comment: yo no veo en tu ejemplo la función fetch que mencionas

Comment: No funcionó. Ya he intentado de varias maneras.